# vb Universal Windows Image Control

Tags: vb.net, win-universal-app

I am switching a vb.net form over to the Universal windows app format and have gotten stuck with switching the PictureBox control. The code in the form format is as follows.

```
 Sub DisplayDie(die As PictureBox, face As Integer)
    die.Image = Image.FromFile(FILE_PREFIX & face & FILE_SUFFIX)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a lot of new concepts you will need to learn before to switch your  code I think your code is from Windows Forms.

First of all there are somethings to know before:

You can't access directly to the folders of the user( C:/ or C:/MyFolder)

You need to enable some special capabilities to access to Documents library , Pictures library

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#special_capabilities

You need to use FileOpenPicker to let the user select some image

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Finally you will get a stream.

Here is an example how to use it

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/open-file-using-fileopenpicker-in-windows-store-app/ 
this code is in C# but is very easy to understand.